# Request validation allways passes on Laravel using Dingo/Api

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5.1, dingo-api

I'm using [dingo/api](https://github.com/dingo/api) package.

Controller:

```
public function register(RegisterUserRequest $request)
{
    dd('a');
}
```

And for example the email field is required:

```
<?php namespace App\Http\Requests;


class RegisterUserRequest extends Request
{
    /**
     * Determine if the user is authorized to make this request.
     *
     * @return bool
     */
    public function authorize()
    {
        return true;
    }

    /**
     * Get the validation rules that apply to the request.
     *
     * @return array
     */
    public function rules()
    {
        return [
            'email' => 'required'
        ];
    }
}
```

So I send a request without the email, and still getting the "a" response.

I also tried to extend `Dingo\Api\Http\Request` instead of `App\Http\Request`, but still the same.

Answer (score 1):

For Dingo to work at all with the *FormRequest*, by experience (and from [this Issue](https://github.com/dingo/api/issues/562)), you have to use *Dingo's* Form request i.e `Dingo\Api\Http\FormRequest;` , so you'll have something similar to:

```
<?
namespace App\Http\Requests;
use Dingo\Api\Http\FormRequest;
use Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Exception\HttpException;


class RegisterUserRequest extends FormRequest
{
    /**
     * Determine if the user is authorized to make this request.
     *
     * @return bool
     */
    public function authorize()
    {
        return true;
    }

    /**
     * Get the validation rules that apply to the request.
     *
     * @return array
     */
     public function rules()
     {
        return [
            'email' => 'required'
        ];
     }
    // In case you need to customize the authorization response
    // although it should give a general '403 Forbidden' error message
    /**
     * Handle a failed authorization attempt.
     *
     * @return mixed
     */
     protected function failedAuthorization()
     {
         if ($this->container['request'] instanceof \Dingo\Api\Http\Request) {
            throw new HttpException(403, 'You cannot access this resource'); //not a user?
         }

     }
}
```

> PS: This is tested on Laravel 5.2.*

Hope it helps :)

Answer (score 0):

According to the [Wiki](https://github.com/dingo/api/wiki/Errors-And-Error-Responses#form-requests)

> you must overload the failedValidation and failedAuthorization methods.
>   These methods must throw one of the above mentioned exceptions and not the response HTTP exceptions that Laravel throws.

If you take a look at Dingo\Api\Http\FormRequest.php, you'll see:

```
class FormRequest extends IlluminateFormRequest
{
    /**
     * Handle a failed validation attempt.
     *
     * @param \Illuminate\Contracts\Validation\Validator $validator
     *
     * @return mixed
     */
    protected function failedValidation(Validator $validator)
    {
        if ($this->container['request'] instanceof Request) {
            throw new ValidationHttpException($validator->errors());
        }

        parent::failedValidation($validator);
    }

    /**
     * Handle a failed authorization attempt.
     *
     * @return mixed
     */
    protected function failedAuthorization()
    {
        if ($this->container['request'] instanceof Request) {
            throw new HttpException(403);
        }

        parent::failedAuthorization();
    }
}
```

Hence, you need to change the names of your methods appropriately, and have them throw the appropriate exceptions, instead of returning a boolean.

Answer (score 0):

you need to call the validate function explicitly when you run it under an Dingo API setup, try something like this (for L5.2):

Probably a few extra providers

```
...
Illuminate\Validation\ValidationServiceProvider::class,
Dingo\Api\Provider\LaravelServiceProvider::class,
...
```

Aliases

```
...
'Validator' => Illuminate\Support\Facades\Validator::class,
...
```

I'm also pretty much sure that you really don't want to use this below as suggested here and there, It will expect form(encoded) input and will also probably fail on CSRF token as it expects it, so it will fail right after validating (form input). But make sure to test behavior with this on/off.

```
use Dingo\Api\Http\FormRequest;
```

Make your headers:

```
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Illuminate\Http\Response;
use App\Http\Requests;
use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;

use Dingo\Api\Exception\ValidationHttpException;
use Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Exception\NotFoundHttpException;

/* This can be a tricky one, if you haven't split up your 
 dingo api from the http endpoint, there are plenty 
 of validators around in laravel package 
*/

use Validator;
```

Then the actual code (if you adhere to cors standard, 
this should be a POST and that commonly translates to a store request)

```
...
/**
* Store a newly created resource in storage.
*
* @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
* @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
*/
public function register(RegisterUserRequest $request) {
    $validator = Validator::make($request->all(), $this->rules());
    if ($validator->fails()) {
        $reply = $validator->messages();
        return response()->json($reply,428);
    };
    dd('OK!');
};
...

/**
* Get the validation rules that apply to the request.
*
* @return array
*/
public function rules()
{
    return [
            'email'   => 'required'
            // or/and 'userid'     => 'required'
    ];
}
```

That will give you back the response you expect from the validator.  If you use this with pregenerated forms, it does not need this fix, there the validator will kick in automatically. (not under Dingo Api).

you probably also need these in composer.json

```
    "dingo/api": "1.0.*@dev",
    "barryvdh/laravel-cors": "^0.7.1",
```

This is untested, by heart, it took me 2 days to figure this out but I have a separate namespace for API specific and authenticated with middleware. success